# Comunicação Bluetooth entre um iPad e um PIN-PAD utilizando Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Preciso de ajuda em como utilizar o Core Bluetooth na comunicação com um PIN-PAD. Eu gostaria de saber se isso é possível, e se for, como posso fazê-lo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá qual a finalidade? Existem outros métodos de comunicação
[Multipeer Connectivity"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/ "Multipeer Connectivity")

Comment: Olá! A finalidade é realizar transações com leitores de cartão de crédito via bluetooth né, mas como estou iniciando no ambiente iOS não possuo ainda muito conhecimento para o mesmo. A principio a ideia é realizar um "link" com o meu dispositivo para que eu possa realizar envio e recebimento de informações com o mesmo. Irei testar essa classe Elias. Muito Obrigado por enquanto!

Answer (score 0):

Entendo, este framework ele faz comunicação entre dispositivos via (WiFi, Bluetooth) envia dados e recebe dados porém teria que verificar qual o tipo de comunicação que e como se recebe e envia.
[MCDemo](https://github.com/abbood/MCDemo) um exemplo se quiser execute ele e faca a comunicação, é um exemplo simples de CHAT, mas que utiliza o framework e seus métodos.